# What should I call $X$ when $U = X \times Y$

Tags: terminology

I'd like to say that $X$ is xyz of $U$ when $U = X \times Y$. I've learnt that $U$ can be called as the direct product of $X$ and $Y$. But I've not learned how to call $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: They are multiplicands in the direct product.

Comment: Why does it matter whether they have a given name or not?  If you really so insist that it must have a name, then you could borrow names from other related concepts, perhaps calling $X$ the multiplicand and $Y$ the multiplier, but I wouldn't bother in the first place.  If I ever had to refer to them, I would do so by name or by a simple phrase such as "the former/(*or latter*) group involved in the product"

Comment: I think factors also works.

Comment: You could use "projection onto the first coordinate", though I would probably define that the first time you used it.

Comment: X is the image of the projection of U onto its (U's) first co-ordinate. Y is the image of the projection of U onto its second co-ordinate. Sometimes we say "X is the projection... (etc)" but the projection onto to the first co-ordinate should mean the function that maps (x,y) in U to x in X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think factor or cartesian factor is a reasonable if you talk about the relation between $X$ and $U$. Also in the case where you consider the expression $U=X\times Y$ it's reasonable to call $X$ and $Y$ (cartesian) factors. After all one calls the expression $X\times Y$ a (cartesian) product.

If you include the term "cartesian" there should probably be little room for misunderstanding what you mean, but on the other hand since it's not a standard term you should perhaps define it somewhere.

On the other hand there are reasons why you might not want to call it a factor (at least without prepending "cartesian"), or call the expression $U=X\times Y$ a factorization of $U$. As far as I see one uses the term `factors` only in (non-abelian) groups or rings, but cartesian product fails to be associative (so we're far from being a ring) and we don't have inverses (so it's as far from being a group).

Also there's probably a reason why there is no standardized name for this. I've never seen situations where it's useful to investigate whether a set have cartesian factors (or is cartesian prime so to say). Also I've not seen a situation where one want to express that $U=X\times Y$ without also having the set $Y$ (otherwise one would just write $U=X\times Y$). Simply there seem not to be much use of such term - and those cases where it **could** be useful one can easily express the same thing easily without a special term.

Comment: The notation $X\times Y$ isn't only used for cartesian products but also could indeed be in reference to a [direct product of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups) (*though it is related to cartesian products, it has deeper meaning as it has implied group structure as well*).

Comment: I assumed that he meant cartesian product from the tagging of the question. However I think that much of what I write applies to direct products as well (after replacing "cartesian" with "direct").